# Solving for weights?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have set returns on few stocks, for example;

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .10 | .12 | .09 | .11 |

I know that I am aiming to allocate the weights in each stock so that I achieve a payoff of .115. How do I solve for this? Im don't think using matrix would work as I the return is one dimensional?

Comment: There are multiple (many) answers to this problem. What criteria would you use to pick only one of them?

Comment: I am not sure I follow you, but the criteria that I'm working with is that there must be a percentage in each stock?

Comment: Your question is a linear programming problem: maximize the return of a portfolio subject to some constraints. What we want to know are constraints: the min and max weight of each stock in the portfolio, relationship between their weights (weight for A must not exceed 150% of the weight for B), etc.

Comment: `0.10w + 0.12x + 0.09y + 0.11z = 0.115`; `x+y+w+z=1`. So you have 2 equation but 4 unknowns, which, in this case, will give you infintely many solutions. If you have 2 more equations, you may get an unique solution.

Comment: I assume adding two more equations which are just the original doubled and tripled would still give an unlimited amount of solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote a, b, c, d as the weight of each stock in the portfolio. We are trying to maximize the portfolio's return:

```
maximize r = 0.1a + 0.12b + 0.09c + 0.11d
```

Subject to the following constraints:

```
0 < a, b, c, d <= 1
a + b + c + d = 1
0.1a + 0.12b + 0.09c + 0.11d = 0.115
```

We will use `scipy.optimize.linprog` to solve this. The function has a peculiar way of accepting inputs:

- It always seeks to *minimize* the objective function
- It expects constraints in 2 forms: `A_ub * x <= b_ub` and `A_eq * x = B_eq`

So we need to restate our problem to make it fit with the way `linprog` works:

```
minimize r' = -0.1a - 0.12b - 0.09c - 0.11d
```

Subject to:

```sh
0.0001 <= a,b,c,d <= 1   # a near-zero lowerbound since
                         # we can't use half-open range
1a + 1b + 1c + 1d = 1
0.1a + 0.12b + 0.09c + 0.11d = 0.115
```

---

Code:

```py
from scipy.optimize import linprog

c = [-0.1, -0.12, -0.09, -0.11]
A = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0.1, 0.12, 0.09, 0.11],
]
b = [
    1,
    0.115,
]

result = linprog(c, A_eq=A, b_eq=b, bounds=(0.0001, 1))
```

Output:

```py
>>> result
     con: array([-9.16875464e-11, -9.32195987e-12])
     fun: -0.11500000000932195
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([], dtype=float64)
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.1159907 , 0.64131022, 0.01265976, 0.23003933])
```

Of course there *many* solutions to this problem. You can get the optimal weights with `result.x`.